How can we compare equilibrium constants if we don't know the solution for the reaction?
I assume that acid and base ionization constants are calculated from water. However if that is true we cannot directly assign these constants to their corresponding acids and bases in some reaction without being certain the solution is water. I see this though. My professor asked us a question where we must look up equilibrium constants for the acids and bases in a table (which I'm assuming is only applicable for reactions in water) and apply those to the reaction formula to determine the whether the reaction would shift to the left or the right. However he never mentioned what the solution was, if it was water or not. I'm confused so how using those values can be valid.
Is it okay to assume the constants would be the same for all mixtures or am I missing something obvious?

Equilibrium constants aren't the same even if solution isn't highly diluted. Still, I seriously doubt it's relevant for your "determining of the equilibrium position".

Please explain what you want ! You say (I copy) : "we must search for the equilibrium constants for the acids and bases in the reaction". Which reaction ? Is it the reaction of these acids and bases with water ? Is it the reaction of any acid with any base ? Please explain !

@Maurice I think I told you there should be not space before exclamation mark? (Or question mark, like I just wrote). Not that I see a reason to write "Please explain" twice in a single comment, even without exclamation marks...

Acid/base dissociation constants are nothing else but equilibrium constants for the general equilibrium $\ce{HA + B <=> A- + BH+}$ where the acidity/basicity of the other conjugate pair, and activity of its form as a solvent (HA for bases B, B for acids HA) are all implicitly involved in the constant.
E.g.:

For acetic acid in water, $\ce{HA = CH3COOH}$, $\ce{B = H2O}$.
For ammonia in water, $\ce{HA = H2O}$, $\ce{B = NH3}$
For sulfuric acid in waterfree (icy) acetic acid, $\ce{HA = H2SO4}$, $\ce{B = CH3COOH}$.

Therefore, it is obvious that dissociation constants are conditional, linked to the particular solvent, which is water by default.
